# How Do I Use Smokescreen/JavaScript to Convert Flash to an Image

Tags: javascript, flash

I have a simple script [from AccuWeather](http://netweather.accuweather.com/signup-page1.asp?partner=&traveler=0) to display a weather button on my website:

[image: Weather button from AccuWeather]

I love the simple way this button displays. It's perfect for what I want.

However, the button generated is in Adobe Flash format (swf) and doesn't display on most mobile devices since iOS and Windows Phone have no support and [Flash Player for Android is no longer available](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1061194) for download from the Google Play app store.

I thought I found a solution in an Open Source project called [Smokescreen](http://smokescreen.us/) that has [its development area at Github](https://github.com/cesmoak/smokescreen).

I don't need this to reproduce flash movies. All I need is a simple javascript-based conversion of the flash button to a flat image that can be displayed in any browser that can execute javascript, which includes mobile devices.

But the documentation and description of how to use Smokescreen at their GitHub site is minimal at best, and I'm not a javascript expert and cannot get it working.

The call I am making that obtains the Flash image from AccuWeather is:

```
<script src='http://netweather.accuweather.com/adcbin/netweather_v2/netweatherV2ex.asp
   ?partner=netweather&tStyle=whteYell&logo=0&zipcode=NAM|CA|MB|WINNIPEG|
   &lang=eng&size=7&theme=blue&metric=1&target=_self'>
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me what the javascript would be to use Smokescreen to display the flash image produced by the above code as an image.

If Smokescreen can't do it, is there any other method that can do this live on a webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested smokescreen with the SWF of the page you posted, and it doesn't work, you will need to parse the SWF at server side if you still want to use that site.

- I opened the dev console and tracked down the SWF from the iframe
- copied the file into my computer, then
- cloned the github repo and
- edited the `player.html` (from the github repo), [line 13](https://github.com/cesmoak/smokescreen/blob/master/player.html#L13) to point to the file I downloaded.

This is the SWF I downloaded: http://netwx.accuweather.com/netWx-V212.swf?zipcode=46958

---

Edit: this is the error message I got from the dev console:

```
TypeError: this.defineEditText is not a function [loader.js:136](https://github.com/cesmoak/smokescreen/blob/master/src/player/loader.js#L136)
```

My system asks for permission to allow the SWF to connect to `netwx.accuweather.com`.

Comment: You've got me started, but it looks like I'll still need a little more to figure this out. It probably can be done, but the demo seems to be calling a "player", and this is a simple image. So maybe there's a different call or something. I've added an issue onto the smokescreen GitHub that hopefully one of developers will see and answer. https://github.com/cesmoak/smokescreen/issues/4

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on github reveals some nice pure javascript alternatives.
https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=weather&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories

I think this one looks the most promising: http://simpleweatherjs.com/

This simpleweatherjs demo shows a nice icon as well: http://codepen.io/fleeting/pen/wHism

Comment: You've given me alternatives (ugly ones), but not an answer to my question as to how to call Smokescreen correctly.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately there is no way your javascript can handle swf, espacially on mobile devices like whith ios or windows phone since the javascript is running on your device itself.

all you could try is to use swfobject which is described as a workaround for javascript

[here is the documentation of swfobject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)

Comment: I'm not the person who -1'd you, but Smokescreen claims their javascript can handle swf. My question is to find out how to call Smokescreen correctly so that I can at least test and see if it will work.

Comment: @lkessler, just tested smokescreen with the SWF of the page you posted, and it doesn't work, you will need to parse the SWF at server side if you still want to use that site.

Comment: @AstDerek - I'm glad you tried it and found that out. But I was simply asking in my question what javascript calls I had to make to try it, because I wanted to play around with it. Obviously, you know the calls required. If you can still give this info as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I opened the dev console, tracked down the SWF from the iframe, copied the file into my computer, then cloned the github repo and edited the `player.html` (from the github repo), [line 13](https://github.com/cesmoak/smokescreen/blob/master/player.html#L13) to point to the file I downloaded. This is the SWF I downloaded: http://netwx.accuweather.com/netWx-V212.swf?zipcode=46958

Comment: @AstDerek - The little you've given me here in the comments is better than all the answers given here so far. If you can add this as an answer (now in the 1 day grace period - not sure you can), I'll give you the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a headless browser like [phantomjs](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture)? You could use something like Selenium instead for out-of-the-box plugin support, but [there are headless options for Flash](http://blog.webogroup.com/2013/04/how-to-setup-completely-headless.html).

The beauty of such software is that it can automate any user task (that's why it's used for testing). Like logging onto a site and performing a search that would normally not be available externally because of antiforgery tokens. Or checking if a product's price has changed by seeing if its DOM element value's has changed. <strike>Or accessing your online banking to see if your balance is a prime number and rendering your credit card bill in fractal form.</strike>

I mean, if you want to go this far for a weather widget, you probably have power user needs :)

...also Accuweather seems to do a fairly similar [mobile-friendly version](http://www.accuweather.com/netwxmobile.asp). And if it's not 100% the same, you could always ask.

**Edit:** check their T&C, the mobile-friendly snippet might actually be the *only* option for legal reasons.

Comment: Unfortunately, their mobile snippet has U.S. locations only. I see now in my question I did not give the link to the legal snippet I was using. I've fixed it now, and the snippet I'm using is legal and is from: http://netweather.accuweather.com/signup-page1.asp?partner=&traveler=0 which allows international locations, but only produces the flash button. I don't understand what the phantomjs solution will do. It seems like it will have to generate the whole web page and then take a picture of it and return the picture. I only want to convert the entire web page. Just the flash buttons.

Comment: @lkessler: phantomjs or similar browsers allow for the page to render on the server. You'll then be able to take a screenshot (or, rather, a partial screenshot of just the button with provided API) and do whatever you want with it - like saving to temporary storage as an image and serving it for your mobile users. The greatest thing about it is that the button will render exactly like in the browser and will not even realise it's sandboxed (can't guarantee the same for smokescreen... especially since I can't find a working demo of it :)

Comment: And being unable to find a working demo, or even instructions on how to use Smokescreen was the reason for my question.